# Tax Calculator overtime calculation incorrect

Tags: c

I've written a tax calculator in C which takes in a number of hours and pay rate and calculates to gross pay, tax, and net pay, but when the number of hours worked is greater than 40 (overtime), the result of the calculation is incorrect, what am I doing wrong?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    //Declare the variables with their data types
    int hoursWorked;
    float wagesPerHour;
   
    //Prompt user to enter the hours worked with a keyboard
    printf("Please enter the hours worked this week: ");
    scanf("%d", &hoursWorked);
    
    //Prompt the user to enter their hourly pay rate
    printf("\nPlease enter your hourly pay rate, ");
    printf("enter it in $XX.XX format: $");
    scanf("%f", &wagesPerHour);
    
    //Declare the variables and date types used to calculate the grossPay and taxes
    /*Calculate the gross pay based on the amount of wagesPerHour entered by the user if hoursWorked is equal to
      or less than 40.  If the hoursWorked is more than 40, then calculate the gross pay for the first 40 hours as
      wagesPerHour hoursWorked and add it to wagesPerHour * 1.5 times the number of hoursWorked over 40*/
    
    float grossPay;
    float tax;
    int overtime = (hoursWorked - 40);
    float oTWagesPerHour = (wagesPerHour * 1.5);
    
    if (hoursWorked<=40){
        grossPay = (hoursWorked * wagesPerHour);
    }
    else {
        grossPay = (grossPay) + (overtime * oTWagesPerHour);
    }
    
    /*Calculate the tax amount based on the grossPay amount equal to or less than 600 times the tax rate of 0.15.
      If the grossPay is more than 600, then calculate the tax amount for the first 600 times the tax rate of 0.20*/
    if (grossPay <= 600) {
        tax = grossPay * 0.15;
    }
    else {
        tax = tax + (grossPay * 0.20);
    }
    
    float netPay;
    netPay = grossPay - tax;
    
    //Print the statements below based on the user input and the calculations for grossPay, tax, and netPay
    printf("\nYou entered %d as the hours worked this week and $%.2f as your hourly pay rate.", hoursWorked, wagesPerHour);
    printf("\nGross Pay:\t $%.2f",grossPay);
    printf("\nTaxes Paid:\t $%.2f", tax);
    printf("\nNet Pay:\t $%.2f", netPay);
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Output with OT (this calculation is NOT correct):

```
Please enter the hours worked this week: 43

Please enter your hourly pay rate, enter it in $XX.XX format: $12.50

You entered 43 as the hours worked this week and $12.50 as your hourly pay rate.
Gross Pay:       $56.25
Taxes Paid:      $8.44
Net Pay:         $47.81
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 5.324 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Output without OT (This calculation is correct):

```
Please enter the hours worked this week: 40

Please enter your hourly pay rate, enter it in $XX.XX format: $12.50

You entered 40 as the hours worked this week and $12.50 as your hourly pay rate.
Gross Pay:       $500.00
Taxes Paid:      $75.00
Net Pay:         $425.00
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 8.067 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this section, you only calculate overtime pay when hours worked > 40 instead of both overtime *and* standard pay:

```c
if (hoursWorked<=40){
    grossPay = (hoursWorked * wagesPerHour);
}
else {
    grossPay = (grossPay) + (overtime * oTWagesPerHour);
}
```

In the second calculation `grossPay` will always be 0 at the start, so the result will just be: `(overtime * oTWagesPerHour)` (i.e., it'll be missing the wages from the first 40 hours of work).

You need to include the 40 hours of standard pay:

```c
if (hoursWorked<=40){
    grossPay = (hoursWorked * wagesPerHour);
}
else {
    grossPay = 40 * wagesPerHour + (overtime * oTWagesPerHour);
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you calculate your overtime so that it's 0 when `hoursWorked < 40`, then you only need 1 calculation:

```c
int overtime = hoursWorked < 40 ? 0 : (hoursWorked - 40);
hoursWorked -= overtime;

grossPay = hoursWorked * wagesPerHour + overtime * oTWagesPerHour;
```

(You can read more about the ternary operator (`?:`) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:))

Comment: Thank you Nick, one more question, as the tax calculation isn't working as expected,  I need it to calculate anything 600 and below at the rate of 0.15  and send that to the output.  Then anything greater than 600 should be calculated at 0.20 and added to the amount calculated at 0.15.  Can you tell me what is wrong with my code that I am not getting this output.  It is calculating 0.20 on the entire gross.

Comment: @AnnetteKitz It's the same issue again, where you're calculating for tax over 600 the first part of your if (where you calculated tax for the first 600) doesn't get run, if you change the body of the else to `tax = 600 * 0.15 + ((grossPay-600) * 0.20)` you should get the result you expect. (the `600 * 0.15` accounts for the first 600, the `((grossPay-600) * 0.20)` accounts for everything _over_ that 600 threshold).

Comment: `if...else...` statements only run the single body that applies, if the `if` part runs, then the `else` part wont

Comment: Thank you, I will get the hang of this, but I appreciate the assistance, that did it and that is what I thought it might be, but I hadn't figured out the correct body for the calculation.